# PHP number_format() decimal .99 is turned to .00

Tags: php, decimal, zero, number-formatting

I want to turn a "dirty" figure into a properly written currency price.
The input figure will be something like 23.99000 and I want to display 23,99 + the Euro symbol.

I use this:

```
$price = number_format($price, 2, ',', '')." &#8364;";
```

But the result will be 23,00 € instead of 23,99 €.

What am I getting wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Probably bad rounding. Please show us the exact contents of `$price` before the operation.

Comment: What is `$price` exactly? A float? A string? Show us a `var_dump($price)`.

Comment: Price is exactly defined as $price = 23.99000

Comment: I used the var_dump and it says STRING

Comment: Then it's a string. Turn it into a float, problem solved :-)

Comment: should then the code be `$price = number_format((float)$price, 2, ',', '')." &#8364;";`? Right?

Comment: This works fine for me, even when price is a string.

Comment: Guys sorry for this, I just discovered I was number_formatting an already formatted "xx,xx €" string, so it didn't turn it to float. Now it's 100% fine! Thank you so much. I'll be bothering you again..

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
<?php
$price = 23.99000;
$price = sprintf("%01,2f", $price).' &euro;';
echo $price;
```

Output:

```
23,99 €
```

the `f` means it'll treat the string as a float, and format accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, but as stated below, I also need to use the comma decimal separator, not the dot one :) Anyway I solved this, I was erroneusly number_formatting the wrong variable (which was already formatted).

Comment: Oh sorry, edited the code to reflect - all you needed to do was change the `.` to a  `,`, simples.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply using round ?

```
$price = round($price, 2)." &#8364;";
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to use european decimal punctuation, i.e. comma instead of dot.

Comment: No, I mean that input figures are with anglosaxon (dot) decimal separator, and I need to convert it to european (comma) decimal separator. This is why I used number_format instead of round()

Comment: Oh ok then you should try to cast your $price into float when calling the number_format

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just discovered how useful stackoverflow.com is. Amazing!